# Finding the error in two approximations of $e$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> The number $e$ can be defined by $e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/n!)$, where $n! = n(n-1)\cdots 2 \cdot 1$ for $n \neq 0$ and $0! = 1$. Compute the absolute error and relative error in the following approximations of $e$:
>   $$\text{(a)} \sum_{n=0}^5 \frac{1}{n!} \qquad \text{(b)} \sum_{n=0}^{10} \frac{1}{n!}$$

Can someone help with the following question as I've no idea where to start from.
I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the definitions of absolute and relative error:

**Absolute error**: $\epsilon_a = |x - x_{\text{approx}}|$

**Relative error**: $\epsilon_{\text{rel}} = |\frac{x - x_{\text{approx}}}{x}|$

Answer (score 0):

For the first the absolute error is given by

$$\varepsilon_\text{abs} = \left|e-\sum\limits_{n=0}^5\frac{1}{n!}\right|$$

and the relative error is given by

$$\varepsilon_{\text{rel}} = \frac{1}{e}\varepsilon_\text{abs} $$
See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativeError.html). Of course, this depends on you actually knowing the value of $e$, but I assume you have a predefined value of it.